# Celery: memory not released from workers running python code

Tags: python, celery

So this isn't the first time this question is asked here, but it's a slight variation.

I have a file conversion task loading in several GB of data files, chopping them up, and writing them into a new format. This task will continously scan for new files and convert them when it finds them.

However, the worker thread/processes (what are they actually) just keep on accumulating memory with every run and eventually all the memory is in use and the server starts swap thrashing.

The workers execute Python code, so a garbage collector should occasionally free up memory. I also try using `del` to clear the larger data objects.

1. I know I could run one task per worker and then have celery recycle the worker. But isn't this inefficient?
2. If this behaviour is normal, why isn't one task per worker the default option? As workers usually need to remain active, wouldn't any system eventually run out of memory?
3. Is there not a way to manually clear the memory from the workers?